# Polymer <core-xhr> - no POST params sent

Tags: post, xmlhttprequest, polymer

I'm desperately trying to send data via POST to a express.js application. The express.js app works fine but for whatever reason the POST data isn't sent to the server properly:

```
var xhrConfig = {
  url: "http://localhost:3000/test",
  body: {"foo": "bar"},
  // body: JSON.stringify({"foo": "bar"}),
  // body: 'foo=bar',
  method: "POST"
};
document.createElement('core-xhr').request(xhrConfig);
```

My express.js `console.log(req.body)` output is always `{}`. No matter if body is sent stringified or raw or JSON. I also tried `params` instead of `body` just to make sure.

I tried the same in jQuery to exclude the possibility of having a bug in my express.js route but `$.ajax({url: 'http://localhost:3000/test', data: {foo: 'bar'}, type: 'POST'});` works perfectly fine.

So what's the reason that `req,body` is always empty? Any ideas?

//edit:

```
body: "foo=bar",
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
```

This one works now but is there a way to be able to use `body: {"foo": "bar"}` instead of converting it to `foo=bar` first?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `core-xhr` is a low level element, and the body object on it's conf doesn't accept a JS object but the string body you want to use.

For the use you describe, you could try `core-ajax`, a higher level element that can be configured with an object. Doc on `core-ajax`: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-ajax.

```
<core-ajax
  auto
  url="http://localhost:3000/test"
  body='{"foo": "bar"}'
  handleAs="json"
  method: "POST"
  on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}"></core-ajax>
```

Hope it helps. If you need a more detailed example, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like express looks at the Content-Type header to determine what type of body it has, below works for me.

```
this.$.xhr.request({
    url: "/my/url", 
    method: "POST",
    headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(survey), 
    callback: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well on Polymer. This problem is very frustrating because there isn't much documentation on Polymer on core-xhr.

As you have already answered the first question yourself, I'll answer the latter: yes/no. If you look at the source of `<core-xhr>`, it just feeds the params straight to `xhr.send(params)`. however, there is a method inside of  called toQueryString, which does what you want to do.

```
toQueryString: function(params) {
    var r = [];
    for (var n in params) {
      var v = params[n];
      n = encodeURIComponent(n);
      r.push(v == null ? n : (n + '=' + encodeURIComponent(v)));
    }
    return r.join('&');
  }
```